# Accessing a specific part of a line with regular expressions

Tags: regex

I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this with regular expressions, but what I want to do is this.

Basically I have a file and I'm reading it line by line and each line in the file looks something like this.

"Hello this data is relatively useless 237 12375"

Now what I want to do is test to see if the value before the last value is within a certain range and if it is print out the first word in the line.

My main issue is that is there a way to access the word before the last word in the line?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the quotes are not actually there and the last two pieces are always digits you could do something like:

`(\d+)\s(?:\d+)`

ie. match any number of digits as long they are followed by a space and other digits

[Try](https://regex101.com/r/aU1oG3/1)

Comment: Yeah, that does work too. I just realized that I can solve the issue easily by basically testing like this (\b[3]\d{2}\b) since I know that the number I am looking at will always have a space before and after it so I don't end up confusing it with larger numbers in the program that may contain a number in it within the range I am looking at.